# Conditional data resource using for each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need to create a conditional data resource for ssm parameters. There are existing ssm parameters on my account which are retrieved using data resource. I need to create ones but retain the data resource for the legacy items. Ideally i want to test for the existence of the ssm resource and if it does not exist then create the ssm resource. The one challenge is that using count leads to further changes downstream which i want to avoid. Can we use for_each instead of count?

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ssm_vpc_id" {
  count = var.somevar == true ? 1 : 0
  name = "/network/${var.deployment}/vpc/id"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter"  "ssm_vpc_id" {
  count = var.somevar == true ? 0 : 1
  name = "/network/${var.deployment}/vpc/id"
  type  = "String"
  value = "aws_vpc.vpc.id"  
}
```

Comment: "Can we use for_each instead of count?" - try and let us know if you get any issues or errors.

Comment: on the data resource i've tried for_each = var.somevar == name ? true : false. I get the error Invalid reference . A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.